# 2 join queries in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

can any one help me on this, Im new with databases and queries. I'm using sqlite; and my database contains 2 tables. edges and nodes .
tables are like:

```
nodes
_______________________
NO     name      family
9808   antony    bits
6757   saly      wood



edges
_______________________
ID     Source    Target
1      9808      6757
2      9808      6757
3      6757      9808
4      6757      9808
5      9808      6757
```

the query should replace source and target with "name&family" and "name&family" then count the frequency of each edges which results in this:

```
Source            target           frequency
"antony bits"     "saly wood"       3
"saly wood"       "antony bits"     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start off with `.mode column`, then run this query:

```
select a.name||' '||a.family as source, b.name||' '||b.family as target, count() as freq from edges as c
left join nodes as a on c.source = a.NO
left join nodes as b on c.target = b.NO
group by source, target
order by freq desc ;
```

output is:

```
source       target       freq
-----------  ----------   ----------
antony bits  saly wood    3
saly wood    antony bits  2
```

The trick is double join the table on the source and target columns.